# Afnetworking respose 500 - response succes second call - Postman - all the time Oky

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking

I develop an app and I use the AFNetworking to comunicate with the server.Everything is oky except one call which return **status code: 500**; second time when I call the WS is oky.

My method :

```
-(IBAction)quizzSubmit:(id)sender {

        BusinessLogic *bl = [BusinessLogic sharedManager];
        
        [AlertDFF alertWithTitle:@"Loading ..." owner:self];
        
        NSString *plm = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[{\"nid\":%d,\"score\":%d,\"time\":%d,\"options\":{\"cid1\":\"%@\",\"cid2\":\"%@\",\"cid3\":\"%@\",\"cid4\":\"%@\",\"cid5\":\"%@\",\"cid6\":\"%@\",\"cid7\":\"%@\",\"cid8\":\"%@\",\"cid9\":\"%@\",\"cid10\":\"%@\"}}]", self.quizzId, self.score, self.time, [self.quizzAnswersDic objectForKey:@"cid1"], [self.quizzAnswersDic objectForKey:@"cid2"], [self.quizzAnswersDic objectForKey:@"cid3"], [self.quizzAnswersDic objectForKey:@"cid4"], [self.quizzAnswersDic objectForKey:@"cid5"], [self.quizzAnswersDic objectForKey:@"cid6"], [self.quizzAnswersDic objectForKey:@"cid7"], [self.quizzAnswersDic objectForKey:@"cid8"], [self.quizzAnswersDic objectForKey:@"cid9"], [self.quizzAnswersDic objectForKey:@"cid10"]];
        
        NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                bl.currentUser.hash, @"hash",
                                plm,@"quizzes",
                                nil];
        
        ApiClientBlitzApp *client = [ApiClientBlitzApp sharedClient];
        NSURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:getQuizSubmit parameters:params];
        
        AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest
*request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id resultObjectsJSON) 
        {
                  if (resultObjectsJSON count]>0){
                        [AlertDFF dismissAlertInController:self];
                        [Utils showAlert:@“Your Quiz Result was sent ! ” andDelegate:nil];
                  }else{
                        [AlertDFF dismissAlertInController:self];
                        [Utils showAlert:@“Problems ! Please try again later! ” andDelegate:nil];
                 }  
            
        }failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR response = %@ /n", response);
            NSLog(@"error     = %@", error);
            [AlertDFF dismissAlertInController:self];
        }];
        [operation start];
    } }



  The WS team told me that my request doesn't reah to the server.
  If I press second time the button and call again the metod everthing it's oky.
  I need some help with this problem please.

  I test the request on Chrome - Postman and everything it's oky.
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Since a `500` error is a internal server error there seems to be something wrong with the server you are calling. There might have something to do with you parameters but a server should not give a `500` error for this. So unless you can share us your server code we can not help you.

Comment: Is there a cookie or token being passed back and forth the first time?

Comment: I attached on my question. the server response. The WS team told me that they make all the investigation and my request "doesn't reah to the server".

Comment: Each reqest have a param called "hash" - which it is generated when user loged in app.I don't have any code about the server part - just discutsion with my WS Team - they told me that everything it's oky from the Android part, but for me thay haven't an answer why I receive "Succes" response from second call.

Comment: Well they're wrong; that response comes from the server.

Comment: I'm little confuse because from the Android part everything it's oky - and I need call twice this WS for succes...My other calls are oky - except this.

Comment: I set in this way the comunication :    [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    self.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;

Comment: @TyronePrude Have you managed to fix it or still not? I am facing same issue.